# What are the different ways of communicating between controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, controller

What are different ways of `controller` communication in `angularJS`?

- Like we can use `require` in one `controller` to show the dependency of
  other `controller` and use it.
- There may be other ways also that I am not aware of?

Comment: Using angular service you can pass value from one controller to other.

Comment: You can use a service to share data between controllers. If controllers are in hierarchy, emit and broadcast can be used. If under same app, rootScope can be used.

Comment: services are your to-go way of communication between controllers. In [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#defer-controller-logic-to-services) he goes on to explain the benefit of doing do. Highly recommend his style guide when starting with angular